# After disabling folder redirection My Documents still redirected

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, folder-redirection

like title says.  I disabled my folder redirection after it became too much of a hassle.  I had been experiencing reorganization of my start menu, links intermittently disabled and then reappearing, and long logon times so I disabled redirected folders.  The start menu and desktop both worked fine and are showing that they are local but when I open My Documents from the start menu it still goes to the redirected folder's copy.  I have restarted twice since then and checked the server and enabled and disabled folder redirection again to to ensure that it enforces that its disabled.  Any ideas what I can do or why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folder redirection GPO settings include an option to remove the redirection or not when the group policy setting no longer applies. By default, this setting is set to leave the redirection in place after the GPO is removed.  So that's probably what happened here.  You removed the GPO, but it was set to keep the redirection in place anyway.

You'll need to go back to your folder redirection GPO and set it redirect back to you local user profile location, instead of just setting folder redirection back to `Not Configured`.  See Image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that saved my day! Same problem 8 years later.